# concatenating pandas dataframes - all objects passed were None

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read and filter a csv file in chunks, and then put the result into a dataframe.

Here is what I use for reading and filtering the csv:

```
csv_chunks = pandas.read_csv(filepath, sep = DELIMITER,skiprows = 2, chunksize = 1000, converters = {"A": str, "B": str})
for chunk in csv_chunks:
    chunk = chunk[(chunk["B"] + chunk["A"]).isin(acids.tolist())]
```

When I go and concatenate the chunks

```
df = pandas.concat(chunk for chunk in csv_chunks)
```

I get an error saying

```
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py
", line 872, in concat
verify_integrity=verify_integrity)
File "C:\Program Files\Python\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py
", line 913, in __init__
raise Exception('All objects passed were None')
Exception: All objects passed were None
```

There are a couple of chunks that are empty, but there are non-empty ones too, so not sure what objects are seen as None. Any thoughts welcome!

Thanks,
Anne

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
csv_chunks = [chunk[(chunk["B"] + chunk["A"]).isin(acids.tolist())]
              for chunk in csv_chunks]
df = pandas.concat(csv_chunks)
```

---

The code

```
for chunk in csv_chunks:
    chunk = chunk[(chunk["B"] + chunk["A"]).isin(acids.tolist())]
```

is probably not doing what you intend. With each iteration of the `for-loop`, `for chunk in csv_chunks` assigns an item in `csv_chunks` to `chunk`. Then,

```
chunk = chunk[(chunk["B"] + chunk["A"]).isin(acids.tolist())]
```

immediately **reassigns** a new value to `chunk`. Fine, but this does not change the items in `csv_chunks`. You are just twiddling the value in some independent variable, `chunk`.

To modify the values in `csv_chunks`, you could use a list comprehension to *build a new list* which is then *reassigned* to the variable `csv_chunks`:

```
csv_chunks = [chunk[(chunk["B"] + chunk["A"]).isin(acids.tolist())]
              for chunk in csv_chunks]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot unutbu, that seems to do the trick. I am used to C++ so tend to get confused by thinking in terms of pointers and pass by value/reference, which I think are not really appropriate describing how Python works. So in a situation as above, how do I know whether I am creating a copy or am actually pointing to the actual object?